# Menu options is not fixing in position when scrolling

Tags: css, html, footer, menuitem

I have a page with listview. And I added the menu options in the footer `"bars"` icon with options(`delete, delete all`). When I'm scrolling for list items in the listview. The menu options also scrolling.

http://jsfiddle.net/GV6K9/3/

When I clicked on the `bars` icons options are opening like (delete, delete all). When I'm scrolled for the list items in the listview up and down along with options are also scrolling. Please check it in fiddle. It's easy to understand the process of working

Answer (score -1):

Don't really understand the wording of your question

Comment: please check fiddle once then you understand easily

Comment: should be comment not a solution